# Пожаротехник и пожарно-технический

Tags: орфография

Как пишутся слова «пожаротехник» и «пожарно-технический»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют слова: **пожаротехник, эксперт-пожаротехник** (встречаются в текстах), **пожаротехника, пожаротехнический, пожарно-технический** (указаны в словаре).

[https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=пожаротехнический&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=0](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=0)

***Пожаротехник, пожаротехника, пожаротехнический*** ― эти слова образованы методом чистого (бессуффиксального) сложения, пишутся слитно.

***Пожарно-технический*** ― сложное прилагательное образовано сложение основ *пожарный* и *технический,* дефисное написание.

Обычно используется прилагательное ***пожарно-технический***: пожарно-технический минимум, пожарно-технический автомобиль.